# Div over image without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck with this... My goal is this page:

[image]

I want to place text over an image, for example "STALDEN". I know how to do this, but when i use absolute positioning and insert a new entry the text is on the same position like to one before. How can I solve this better?

Any help much appreciated!

This is what i have:

```
<div class="karte">
      <img src="img/home/stalden.png" alt="">
      <h1>STALDEN</h1>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.karte img {
  width: 100vw;
}


.karte h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15vw;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use image as background?

Comment: have you tried relative position?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use image as background of your section

```css
.karte {
  background: url('img/home/stalden.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="karte">
  <h1>STALDEN</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: **It's solution**. Should be marked as answer, i think.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.karte{
  position: relative;
}

.karte img{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.karte h1{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50px;
 left: 50px;
}
```

It's exactly that you ask. But it's better to use `background-image` here because of better semantic and other reasons... Just use `background-image`. It's better solution.